# Use Google Pay response token in Stripe api

Tags: stripe-payments, google-pay

I have set up the Google Pay button on my page by following Google Pay documentation, but i got stuck in the last step where i need to send the token response from Google Pay to Stripe as the Google Pay document describe.

> To execute the payment, the backend processes the purchase and sends the payment token to the payment service provider.

I have search the Stripe documentation but can't seem to find how to use that token but instead they show me how to use Stripe **Payment Request Button** to integrate Google Pay.
So, does stripe support token from Google Pay api or do i need to use Stripe **Payment Request Button** to integrate with Google Pay?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do either and you don't / shouldn't mix the two approach

Based on the [Stripe doc here](https://stripe.com/docs/google-pay#web) You can either use

1. Stripe's PaymentRequestButton
2. OR you can integrate with Google Pay directly using Stripe as a gateway. See how to do it [here](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/tutorial); in Step 2 of the tutorial, search `stripe` to find the gateway configurations

```
const tokenizationSpecification = {
  type: 'PAYMENT_GATEWAY',
  parameters: {
    "gateway": "stripe"
    "stripe:version": "2018-10-31" // your stripe API version
    "stripe:publishableKey": "pk_test_xxxx" // your stripe publishable key
  }
};
```

For option 2, you will basically get a Stripe token like this `tok_xxxx` represent the GooglePay wallet from `paymentData.paymentMethodData.tokenizationData.token`, and you can use the token directly with Stripe API using your Stripe's secret key `sk_test_xxxx` e.g. create a charge [following this](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create?lang=node#create_charge-source)

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_xxxxx');

const charge = await stripe.charges.create({
  amount: 2000,
  currency: 'usd',
  source: 'tok_obtained_from_google_pay_api', 
  description: 'My First Test Charge (created for API docs)',
});
```

FYI `token/charge` API is no longer recommended, you can create a `payment_method` from the `token` like [this](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/create?lang=node#create_payment_method-card)

```
const paymentMethod = await stripe.paymentMethods.create({
  type: 'card',
  card: {
    token: 'tok_xxxxx',
  },
});
```

and use it with Stripe [PaymentIntent API](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/intents)